# Detecting When A Control Moves On Canvas in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, hittest

I have a custom UserControl who's position is bound to parameters in a ViewModel.

```
<Canvas Name="CursorCanvas">
    <ctrl:HandCursor x:Name="RightHandCursor" State="{Binding RightHandState}" Visibility="{Binding IsHandTracking, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" Canvas.Top="{Binding RightHandY}" Canvas.Left="{Binding RightHandX}" />
</Canvas>
```

Inside of this control I am performing a HitTest, to determine what is below it.  Currently this HitTest is hooked up to a DispatcherTimer ta 1-second intervals.  What I'd rather do tell the control to perform the HitTest when it moves on the Canvas, but I am unable to find how to capture the Canvas position updates in the UserControl that is being moved.

How can I capture the Canvas.Top/Left movement updates in the code-behind for the "HandCursor" UserControl defined above?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you really need to track the position of the cursor from the cursor itself? Can't you track the position on the canvas using the MouseMove event on the canvas?

Comment: I am not using the mouse.  This is a custom control who's x/y is updated via a different input device (Kinect, to be specific).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.PropertyChangedCallback.aspx) by overriding the property metadata of the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties:

```
static HandCursor()
{
    Canvas.LeftProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(HandCursor),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            (o, e) => ((HandCursor)o).LeftPropertyChanged((double)e.NewValue)));

    Canvas.TopProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(HandCursor),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            (o, e) => ((HandCursor)o).TopPropertyChanged((double)e.NewValue)));
}

private void LeftPropertyChanged(double left)
{
    ...
}

private void TopPropertyChanged(double top)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Clemens.  My custom cursor is now timer free!